# Open Html file from Heroku Bash

Tags: javascript, html, python, heroku, browser

I have deployed my Flask python application on Heroku. The problem is that in one line of my python code I must open an HTML file (where some javascript gets executed).

Obviously, it locally works in my mac, but in Heroku it doesn't' seem to recognise the 'open' command, in fact I get:

> /bin/sh: 1: open: not found

This is the python code in my script:

```
p = Popen('open last.html', shell=True)
```

I need the file to be opened to get the javascript executed.
Is there a way to solve this and get the HTML file to be opened?

Answer (score 0):

While some Linux systems may have an `open` command (mine does) that has different semantics, `open` in the sense you're using it is Mac OS X-specific.

This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264395/linux-equivalent-of-the-mac-os-x-open-command) covers a number of alternatives to `open` on a Linux-based environment, with the clearest analogue being `xdg-open`. You'll have to evaluate what the best option is in your Heroku dyno environment based on the tools you've got available there, but it's very unlikely to be called `open`.